# Angular type-ahead directive and using objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using an auto complete directive with angular and I am trying to modify it slightly so it will look through 2 different parts of an object. Let me show you what I mean:

Here is the auto complete directive -

```
.directive('autocomplete', function($timeout){
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.autocomplete({
           source: function( request, response ) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
                    response( $.grep( scope[iAttrs.uiItems], function( item ){
                    return matcher.test( item );
                    }) );
            },                //scope[iAttrs.uiItems]
            select: function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                  iElement.trigger('input');
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    };
})
```

Here is the input-

```
<input type="text" ng-model="keywordHere" ng-keyup="keywordSerch()" autocomplete ui-items="allTags">
```

And lastly the fucntion in the controller -

```
//keyword seach function
$scope.allTags = [];
$scope.keywordSerch = function(){
    $scope.allTags = [];
    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url : "/lessonSearch/1",
            type : "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: { keywords: $scope.keywordHere
            }
        })
        .success(function(data){
            if(data.results){
            angular.forEach(data.results, function(index) {
                $scope.allTags.push(index);

            });
        }
        });
}
```

So what this does is calls the sever to bring back the top 10 items based off of what was typed in (in every keystroke) - so it will return upto 10 items for the autocomplete to work with.

This works fine if I specify a key inside the object - for example in the success of the $http call if i specify $scope.allTags.push(index.name). So if I specify .name, or .id it will return them just fine, and this auto complete directive will work great.

What I am trying to accomplish is being able to pass the object, then have the auto complete look at both the id and name (index.id and index.name in the example provided) and then return the full object, so I can then use it below and reference it's name and ID. So basically regardless if the user typed in an ID or name, autocomplete would look at either based on the returned results (from the call) and then return the full object based on selection.

Would much appreciate any help. Thanks for taking the time to read!